# Pre Commit Hook Gives Unexpected Result (SVN)

Tags: svn, cmd, pre-commit-hook

I have a pre commit hooks as shown below. The Goal of the hook is to make sure the length of the log message is at least 20 characters with one exception being a log message with `Adding Directory`. In this case too the hook should allow to commit but it does not.

```
REM Start
REM Pre Commit hook for having a comment of at least 20 characters. 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set REPOS=%1
set TXN=%2

set SVNLOOK="%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\svnlook.exe"

SET LOGSTRING=

REM Concatenate all the lines in the commit message
FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %%g IN (`%SVNLOOK% log -t %TXN% %REPOS%`) DO SET LOGSTRING=!LOGSTRING!%%g

REM Make sure LOGSTRING is defined
SET LOGSTRING=0%LOGSTRING%

REM EA String Exception Added here
IF %LOGSTRING%" == "Adding Directory"
echo "Exceptional Commit with a Small Message (Generated From EA)" 
goto NORMAL_EXIT

REM Here the 20 is the length we require
IF NOT "%LOGSTRING:~20,1%"=="" 
goto NORMAL_EXIT

:ERROR_TOO_SHORT
echo "Commit note must be at least 20 letters" >&2
goto ERROR_EXIT

:ERROR_EXIT
exit /b 1

REM All checks passed, so allow the commit.
:NORMAL_EXIT
exit 0
```

The issue is that when I have a log message `Adding Directory`. I get Error output with `255(-1)` as the output. I am not used to this script. It's a code put together by using some logic and copy from different websites. Am I missing something very basic in this.

Comment: A zero ("0") has been added at the beginning of the LOGSTRING variable. `SET LOGSTRING=0%LOGSTRING%`. It will no longer be equal to `"Adding Directory"`.

Comment: @lit . Okay! but it shall still have a exit with code 1 and not -1. Don't you think so?

Comment: Please run it and report.

Comment: @lit It gives -1 as the output

Comment: Perhaps it is considering the `255` as a byte. That would be `-1`.